# how to make .htaccess always request password

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http

Is it possible to make htaccess request a password every time, not just e.g. clearing the cache?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by "normal" means. Not because it would not be possible to implement a request for authentication of each and every request, in fact that has probably already been done by you.

Instead the issue simply is that the client side browser with automatically serve the authentication credentials thus prevent the authentication popup to appear, so be visualized to the user. Browsers cache those credentials for pretty obvious reasons: exactly to *prevent* the user to be reprompted for each and every request.

The only "workarounds" I can imagine:

1. to always deny access for a legitimately authenticated request upon each *first* request, but only to grant access for each *second* request. This sounds like a horrible architecture, though. No idea what side effects this would produce...
2. to serve each request from a different hostname (sometimes called a "subdomain"). In that case the browser will obviously *not* reuse the cached credentials, since the pages would appear as separate sites. This should easily be doable if you can use wildcard DNS entries to resolve all arbitrary hostnames to the same IP address and if you can configure a default host on the server side.
3. each page could ask for *different* authentication credentials. Maybe along the scheme: page title as username and always the same password. in combination with for example Linuxs great PAM "authority glue" it should easily be possible to implement such an authentication scheme. But I doubt this is what you are looking for :-)

In short:

- you are probably trying to solve the wrong question
- maybe you should start thinking about what issue you *really* want to solve instead of *how* you think you can solve it

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I suspected that this is not possible by "normal" means ;-)

Comment: @JakobBenz You are welcome! Note that the options I suggested are not complicated to implement at all. So there _are_ options for this. However it is a somewhat strange request which is why I asked the questions towards the end... So this all boils down to: yes, possible, but you have to do it, no single-command-enable-option.